# No network controllers detected in Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS L502X with a Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000

Tags: networking, 16.04, dell

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS L502X with a Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000. Neither the wireless nor ethernet connections appears to be detected, and I'm not sure how to proceed.  I've tried reinstalling, but no help. Here's the output of the wireless-info script:

```
    ########## wireless info START ##########

    Report from: 14 Sep 2016 16:52 EDT -0400

    Booted last: 14 Sep 2016 00:00 EDT -0400

    Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

    ##### release ###########################

    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial

    ##### kernel ############################

    Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

    ##### desktop ###########################

    Ubuntu

    ##### lspci #############################

    ##### lsusb #############################

    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0781:5406 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro U3
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:2fb1 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

    ##### rfkill ############################

    ##### lsmod #############################

    dell_wmi               16384  0
    sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
    dell_laptop            20480  0
    dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
    mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
    wmi                    20480  3 dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
    video                  40960  4 i915,dell_wmi,nouveau,dell_laptop

    ##### interfaces ########################

    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    ##### ifconfig ##########################

    ##### iwconfig ##########################

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    ##### route #############################

    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

    ##### resolv.conf #######################

    ##### network managers ##################

    Installed:

        NetworkManager

    Running:

    root      2225     1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

    ##### NetworkManager info ###############

    ##### NetworkManager.state ##############

    [main]
    NetworkingEnabled=true
    WirelessEnabled=true
    WWANEnabled=true

    ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
    dns=dnsmasq

    [ifupdown]
    managed=false

    ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

    ##### iw reg get ########################

    Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

    country 00: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
        (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

    ##### iwlist channels ###################

    lo        no frequency information.

    ##### iwlist scan #######################

    lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

    ##### module infos ######################

    ##### module parameters #################

    ##### /etc/modules ######################

    ##### modprobe options ##################

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
    blacklist ath_pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
    blacklist evbug
    blacklist usbmouse
    blacklist usbkbd
    blacklist eepro100
    blacklist de4x5
    blacklist eth1394
    blacklist snd_intel8x0m
    blacklist snd_aw2
    blacklist i2c_i801
    blacklist prism54
    blacklist bcm43xx
    blacklist garmin_gps
    blacklist asus_acpi
    blacklist snd_pcsp
    blacklist pcspkr
    blacklist amd76x_edac

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
    alias net-pf-3 off
    alias net-pf-6 off
    alias net-pf-9 off
    alias net-pf-11 off
    alias net-pf-12 off
    alias net-pf-19 off
    alias net-pf-21 off
    alias net-pf-36 off

    [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
    remove iwlwifi \
    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

    [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
    softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

    ##### rc.local ##########################

    exit 0

    ##### pm-utils ##########################

    ##### udev rules ########################

    ##### dmesg #############################

    ########## wireless info END ############
```

I'd appreciate any advice.  Thanks!
As asked for in the comments, here is the `lspci` output:

```
    bonefish@bbonsign:~$ sudo lspci
    [sudo] password for bonefish: 
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
    00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
    00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci` terminal command.

Comment: There was no need to use `sudo`. Network controllers really are not detected. Check that they are not disabled in BIOS.

Comment: As far as I can tell they are not disabled.